# JPA query returning a Tuple where one part is an Entity

Tags: jpa

I have two unrelated tables that I want to do an LEFT JOIN on, I only want 1 column from the LEFT table but the entire entity (which I intend to update if its present or create if not) from the right.

Simplified version of tables:

```
TABLE1
id, type, data

TABLE2
id, type, and, other, stuff
```

Current JPQL:

```
SELECT T1.type,
 (SELECT T2 
  FROM TABLE2 T2 
  WHERE T2.id = T1.id 
  AND T2.type = T1.type) 
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.id = :ID
```

I am currently getting some sort of logical union error...

Can this been done or should I just use separate queries?

The exact exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect incompatible with org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl
```

The Java code I use follows:

```
Query q = this.em.createQuery(jql, Tuple.class);
q.setParameter("ID", id);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Tuple> result = q.getResultList();
```

The subquery is not essential to my solution - it's just the only form that was parseable - a regular SQL LEFT JOIN wasn't.  In words what I am trying to do is for a given ID in TABLE1 find all rows in TABLE2 that have the same ID and type or null if there is no row.  Later code will create rows in TABLE2 where there are none for the id and type.  I'm expecting 2-3 types per ID in TABLE1 and about half the time for a matching row in TABLE2.

Comment: Could you please add corresponding part of your java code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suqueries in select clause with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292651/suqueries-in-select-clause-with-jpa)